# Hover state Heirachy Issues

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

I'm working on a very simple website that takes up sizes to the viewport.

I've used Flexbox to center 3 things in the middle of the viewport. My intention is for one block of text to disappear when hovered over and another block to appear at the same time.

In the sample code below class "headline" is what should disappear and "sub-headline" which is initially hidden should reappear.

I've gotten it to "almost" work by applying the hover state changes to the div "container", however since a couple of the containers inside use width and height of 100% to center in the viewport the hover states take effect anytime the mouse is anywhere on the viewport.

I attempted to apply the hover state to the "headline" container, which is not set to fill the viewport, however I can't figure out how to get the sub-headline opacity to change.

My understanding was the CSS below for hover would work if they were both contained with in the same parent container, but it's not working in this instance.

CSS

```
.headline:hover {opacity:0}
.headline:hover > .sub-headline {opacity:1}



<div class="container">
<div class="bg-image"></div>
<div class="headline">Headline Text</div>
<div class="sub-headline">Sub-Headline Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="bg-image"></div>
<div class="headline">Headline Text</div>
<div class="sub-headline">Sub-Headline Text</div>
</div>
```

Your selector is incorrect as you are using the general descendant selector `>`

This:

```
.headline:hover {opacity:0}
.headline:hover > .sub-headline {opacity:1}
```

Should be this: Using the adjacent selector `+`

```
.headline:hover {opacity:0}
.headline:hover + .sub-headline {opacity:1}
```

Alternative Using a more general sibling selector `~` depending on your requirement.

```
.headline:hover {opacity:0}
.headline:hover ~ .sub-headline {opacity:1}
```

[**The 30 CSS Selectors You Must Memorize**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: Nice link - I never knew about `:only-child`... Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without seeing more of your code as it may be different in your scenario...

You're using a direct descendant selctor (`>`), you should be using the adjacent sibling selector (`+`)

```css
.headline:hover {opacity:0}
.headline:hover + .sub-headline {opacity:1}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-image"></div>
  <div class="headline">Headline Text</div>
  <div class="sub-headline">Sub-Headline Text</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, wrap the sub-heading within the heading and it should work as expected using the direct descendant selector as in your original question (note - I've used the `visibility` property instead of `opacity` for this example):

```css
.headline:hover {visibility: hidden;}
.headline:hover > .sub-headline {visibility: visible;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-image"></div>
  <div class="headline">Headline Text
    <div class="sub-headline">Sub-Headline Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```